# error con php y mysql con la sentacia $stmt->execute();

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, web, intellij-idea

este codigo es un carpeta subcarpeta  de nombre config.php de mismo proyecto

```html
<?php
define('SERVIDOR','localhost');
define('USUARIO','root');
define('PASSWORD','$J91p0324$');
define('BD','sisfarmacia');

$URL = 'http://localhost/www.sisfarmacias.com';

$servidor = "mysql:dbname=" .BD. ";host=" .SERVIDOR;

try {

    $pdo = new PDO($servidor, USUARIO, PASSWORD, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND=>"SET NAMES utf8"));
    echo "<script>alert('La conexion a la base de datos fue exitosa.')</script>";
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

} catch (PDOException $e) {

    echo "<script>alert('Error a la conexion con la base de datos.')</script>";

} finally {

    $pdo=null;
}

?>
```

y es llamado desde otro subcarpeta de nombre controller.php la cual con el metodo include se trata de llamar a config.php

```html
<?php

include ('../app/config/config.php');

$nombres = $_POST['nombres'];
$apellido1 = $_POST['apellido1'];
$apellido2 = $_POST['apellido2'];
$cc = $_POST['cc'];
$fecha_nacimiento = $_POST['fecha_nacimiento'];
$pais = $_POST['pais'];
$celular = $_POST['celular'];
$codigo_postal = $_POST['codigo_postal'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$cargo = $_POST['cargo'];

$user_creacion = "jposso@ut.edu.co";
date_default_timezone_set("America/Bogota");
$fechaHora = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
$estado = '1';

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tb_usuarios 
    (nombres, apellido1, apellido2, cc, fecha_nacimiento, pais, celular, codigo_postal,
     email, password, cargo, user_creacion, fyh_creacion, estado) 

    VALUES (:nombres, :apellido1, :apellido2, :cc, :fecha_nacimiento, :pais, :celular, :codigo_postal,
        :email, :password, :cargo, :user_creacion, :fyh_creacion, :estado)");


$stmt->bindParam(':nombres', $nombres);
$stmt->bindParam(':apellido1', $apellido1);
$stmt->bindParam(':apellido2', $apellido2);
$stmt->bindParam(':cc', $cc);
$stmt->bindParam(':fecha_nacimiento', $fecha_nacimiento);
$stmt->bindParam(':pasi', $pais);
$stmt->bindParam(':celular', $celular);
$stmt->bindParam(':codigo_postal', $codigo_postal);
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
$stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);
$stmt->bindParam(':cargo', $cargo);
$stmt->bindParam(':user_creacion', $user_creacion);
$stmt->bindParam(':fyh_creacion', $fechaHora);
$stmt->bindParam(':estado', $estado);

$stmt->execute();
```

pero cuando se ejecuta en la pagina web sale un error en la linar del (45) donde se encuentra $stmt->execute() que el encargado de ejecutarse y el error es: **Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\www.sisfarmacias.com\usuarios\controller_create.php:45 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\www.sisfarmacias.com\usuarios\controller_create.php(45): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\www.sisfarmacias.com\usuarios\controller_create.php on line 45**; además que el editor de código hay un error: líneas (22) donde esta $pdo donde indica Undefined variable '$pdo' el cual no entiendo por indica que no ha sido definida la variable si en la subcarpeta config.php así declarada en el try de la conexión a la base de datos me podrían ayudar gracias.

Comment: Buenas, John, bienvenido al sitio. No dice nada de una variable no definida. Dice que no has definido ese parámetro en tu consulta. Tienes una errata en una instrucción bindParam, pone "aplllido1" en lugar de "apellido1"

Answer (score 0):

Bien, en tu código tienes varios errores de digitación:
en tu query llamas a los siguientes parámetros:

```
:apellido1, :pais
```

y en tus bindParam mandas los siguientes parámetros:

```
:aplllido1, :pasi
```

Corrige esos errores para que coincida lo que mandas con lo que llamas.